# Links doesn't work on mobile / touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use XSwitch.js at my project and everything is perfect in Desktop view. But when I try to open the link from mobile / touch device seems like nothing happens. It's at 100% not a problem of z-index and positioning. As you can see if you try to click on the Example link on any section you'll can't open the link from mobile. / touch. I tested the issue with iPhone X, Galaxy Tab and Chrome Dev tools. I broke my head of trying to solve this bug and would much appreciate any help. Thanks!

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.XSwitch = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var _this = $(this),
        instance = _this.data('XSwitch');

      if (!instance) {
        instance = new XSwitch(_this, options);
        _this.data('XSwitch', instance);
      }

      if ($.type(options) === 'string') {
        return instance[options]();
      }
    });
  }

  $.fn.XSwitch.defaults = {
    selectors: {
      sections: '.sections',
      section: '.section',
      page: '.pages',
      active: '.active'
    },
    index: 0,
    easing: 'ease',
    duration: 500,
    loop: true,
    pagination: true,
    keyboard: true,
    direction: 'vertical',
    callback: ''
  }


  var _prefix = (function(temp) {
    var aPrefix = ['webkit', 'moz', 'o', 'ms'],
      props = '';
    for (var i = 0, len = aPrefix.length; i < len; i++) {
      props = aPrefix[i] + 'Transition';
      if (temp.style[props] !== undefined) {
        return '-' + aPrefix[i].toLowerCase() + '-';
      }
      return false;
    }
  })(document.createElement('div'));

  var XSwitch = (function() {
    function XSwitch(element, options) {

      this.settings = $.extend(true, $.fn.XSwitch.defaults, options);
      this.element = element;
      this.init();
    }
    XSwitch.prototype = {

      init: function() {
        var _this = this;
        this.selectors = this.settings.selectors;

        this.sections = this.element.find(this.selectors.sections);
        this.section = this.sections.find(this.selectors.section);


        this.direction = this.settings.direction === 'vertical' ? true : false;

        this.pagesCount = this.pagesCount();

        this.index = (this.settings.index >= 0 && this.settings.index < this.pagesCount) ? this.settings.index : 0;

        this.canScroll = true;


        if (!this.direction) {
          _initLayout(_this);
        }

        if (this.settings.pagination) {
          _initPaging(_this);
        }

        _initEvent(_this);
      },

      pagesCount: function() {
        return this.section.size();
      },

      switchLength: function() {
        return this.duration ? this.element.height() : this.element.width();
      },

      prve: function() {
        var _this = this;

        if (this.index > 0) {
          this.index--;
        } else if (this.settings.loop) {
          this.index = this.pagesCount - 1;
        }
        _scrollPage(_this);
      },

      next: function() {
        var _this = this;
        if (this.index < this.pagesCount) {
          this.index++;
        } else if (this.settings.loop) {
          this.index = 0;
        }
        _scrollPage(_this);
      }
    };

    function _initLayout(_this) {
      var width = (_this.pagesCount * 100) + '%',
        cellWidth = (100 / _this.pagesCount).toFixed(2) + '%';

      _this.sections.width(width);
      _this.section.width(cellWidth).css('float', 'left');
    }

    function _initPaging(_this) {

      var pagesClass = _this.selectors.page.substring(1),
        pageHtml = '<ul class="' + pagesClass + '">';
      _this.activeClass = _this.selectors.active.substring(1);

      for (var i = 0, len = _this.pagesCount; i < len; i++) {
        pageHtml += '<li></li>';
      }
      pageHtml += '</ul>';

      _this.element.append(pageHtml);
      var pages = _this.element.find(_this.selectors.page);
      _this.pageItem = pages.find('li');
      _this.pageItem.eq(_this.index).addClass(_this.activeClass);
      if (_this.direction) {
        pages.addClass('vertical');
      } else {
        pages.addClass('horizontal');
      }
    }

    function _initEvent(_this) {

      _this.element.on('click touchstart', _this.selectors.page + ' li', function() {
        _this.index = $(this).index();
        _scrollPage(_this);
      });

      _this.element.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
        if (!_this.canScroll) {
          return;
        }

        var delta = -e.originalEvent.detail || -e.originalEvent.deltaY || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;

        if (delta > 0 && (_this.index && !_this.settings.loop || _this.settings.loop)) {
          _this.prve();
        } else if (delta < 0 && (_this.index < (_this.pagesCount - 1) && !_this.settings.loop || _this.settings.loop)) {
          _this.next();
        }
      });

      _this.element.on('touchstart', function(e) {

        var startX = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX,
          startY = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY;
        _this.element.one('touchend', function(e) {
          if (!_this.canScroll) {
            return;
          }
          var endX = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX,
            endY = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY,
            changeY = endY - startY;
          if (changeY > 50) {
            _this.prve();
          } else if (changeY < -50) {
            _this.next();
          }

        });
        e.preventDefault();
      });

      if (_this.settings.keyboard) {
        $(window).on('keydown', function(e) {
          var keyCode = e.keyCode;
          if (keyCode === 37 || keyCode === 38) {
            _this.prve();
          } else if (keyCode === 39 || keyCode === 40) {
            _this.next();
          }
        });
      }

      $(window).resize(function() {
        var currentLength = _this.switchLength(),
          offset = _this.settings.direction ? _this.section.eq(_this.index).offset().top : _this.section.eq(_this.index).offset().left;

        if (Math.abs(offset) > currentLength / 2 && _this.index < (_this.pagesCount - 1)) {
          _this.index++;
        }
        if (_this.index) {
          _scrollPage(_this);
        }
      });

      _this.sections.on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend', function() {
        _this.canScroll = true;
        if (_this.settings.callback && type(_this.settings.callback) === 'function') {
          _this.settings.callback();
        }
      });
    }

    function _scrollPage(_this) {
      var dest = _this.section.eq(_this.index).position();
      if (!dest) {
        return;
      }
      _this.canScroll = false;
      if (_prefix) {
        _this.sections.css(_prefix + 'transition', 'all ' + _this.settings.duration + 'ms ' + _this.settings.easing);
        var translate = _this.direction ? 'translateY(-' + dest.top + 'px)' : 'translateX(-' + dest.left + 'px)';
        _this.sections.css(_prefix + 'transform', translate);
      } else {
        var animateCss = _this.direction ? {
          top: -dest.top
        } : {
          left: -dest.left
        };
        _this.sections.animate(animateCss, _this.settings.duration, function() {
          _this.canScroll = true;
          if (_this.settings.callback && type(_this.settings.callback) === 'function') {
            _this.settings.callback();
          }
        });
      }

      if (_this.settings.pagination) {
        _this.pageItem.eq(_this.index).addClass(_this.activeClass).siblings('li').removeClass(_this.activeClass);
      }
    }
    return XSwitch;
  })();

})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  $('[data-XSwitch]').XSwitch();
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container,
.sections,
.section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.section {
  background-color: #000;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#section0 {
  background-color: grey;
}

#section1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#section2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" data-XSwitch>
  <div class="sections">
    <div class="section" id="section0">
      <a href="example.com">Example Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section1">
      <a href="example.com">Example Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">
      <a href="example.com">Example Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section3">
      <a href="example.com">Example Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've found an issue - just commented this code:

```
            _this.element.on('touchstart', function (e) {

                var startX = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX,
                    startY = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY;
                _this.element.one('touchend', function (e) {
                    if (!_this.canScroll) {
                        return;
                    }
                    var endX = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX,
                        endY = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY,
                        changeY = endY - startY;
                    if (changeY > 50) {
                        _this.prve();
                    } else if (changeY < -50) {
                        _this.next();
                    }

                }); 
                /* e.preventDefault(); */
            });
```